# Fancybox YouTube not working on iPad or iPhone

Tags: jquery, youtube, fancybox, youtube-api, fancybox-2

I notice that the official Fancybox youtube implementation JSfiddle doesn't work on iOs, any ideas why?

http://jsfiddle.net/M78zz

http://jsfiddle.net/M78zz/show/

```
// Fires whenever a player has finished loading
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
}

// Fires when the player's state changes.
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    // Go to the next video after the current one is finished playing
    if (event.data === 0) {
        $.fancybox.next();
    }
}

// The API will call this function when the page has finished downloading the JavaScript for the player API
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {

    // Initialise the fancyBox after the DOM is loaded
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox")
            .attr('rel', 'gallery')
            .fancybox({
                openEffect  : 'none',
                closeEffect : 'none',
                nextEffect  : 'none',
                prevEffect  : 'none',
                padding     : 0,
                margin      : 50,
                beforeShow  : function() {
                    // Find the iframe ID
                    var id = $.fancybox.inner.find('iframe').attr('id');

                    // Create video player object and add event listeners
                    var player = new YT.Player(id, {
                        events: {
                            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
    });

}
```

The fancybox opens, the youtube video loads and then looks like it is going to start to play, then I just get a black screen.  This is happening on both iPhone and iPad.

Can anyone help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fancybox - Video auto close function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20855414/fancybox-video-auto-close-function)

Comment: Based on your comment, I did and edit to my answer explaining why http://stackoverflow.com/a/20863405/1055987 specifically, youtube on iOS doesn't seem to like `event.target.playVideo();`, which runs before the video is converted into HTML5 format

Answer (score 0):

This question seems to come up quite a bit, and it's very likely your issue is due to the fact that, in Mobile Safari, javascript is prohibited from autoplaying or progammatically starting playback of anything in a  tag (which, since there is no flash, is how YouTube would be serving the videos there). Rather, Mobile Safari requires a user to have to initiate the playback (presumably so a user doesn't use up cellular data without intending to).

Hence, if fancybox relies on programmatic playback (i.e. `event.target.playVideo()`), it isn't compatible with Mobile Safari.

[More info](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH5-SW4)