# Mute YouTube Video in FancyBox

Tags: jquery, youtube, fancybox, fancybox-2, mute

I want to mute youtube video that is initially hidden, when I click a link it opens with FancyBox?v=2.1.5. 
Now I want to mute the video, which is popup via FancyBox. If I use YouTube Api to mute video, the video is shown from hidden. But I want it's show on popup not without popup.

Code is:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".various").fancybox({
    type: "iframe", //<--added
    maxWidth: 800,
    maxHeight: 600,
    fitToView: false,
    width: '70%',
    height: '70%',
    autoSize: false,
    closeClick: false,
    helpers: {
      overlay: {
        locked: false
      }
    }

  });
  
});
```

```html
<a class="various fancybox" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/jid2A7ldc_8?autoplay=1&showinfo=0&enablejsapi=1&hl=es&cc_lang_pref=es&cc_load_policy=1">Click To Open Video</a>
```

Comment: Check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/20863405/1055987
Then inside the `onPlayerReady()` function add:
`event.target.mute()`
From that thread, see [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/61mv8b2m/) with a muted video

Comment: Thank You very much. I fix this.
In advance, Happy New Year